# refresh dom after appendto btn on resizing

Tags: html, jquery, css, append

I am trying to do adaptive on my webpage, and i dound this function

```
  var isBreakPoint = function (bp) {
    var bps = [320, 885, 1440],
      w = $(window).width(),
      min, max
    for (var i = 0, l = bps.length; i < l; i++) {
      if (bps[i] === bp) {
        min = bps[i - 1] || 0
        max = bps[i]
        break
      }
    }
    return w > min && w <= max
  }
```

so, it works perfectrly, and i need on some point to move button from one section to another, so i use

```
 if (isBreakPoint(885)) {
       $('.header__register-link').appendTo($('.header__bottom'))
  }
```

it works almost perfectly too, but the only proble - i need to reaload my page after it hits 885 to see changes...
is it possible to reaload page automaticly when it hits 885, or somehow make changes show without refresh...
thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if statement` is called on browser resize, or is it called on browser refresh.

Did you try adding your if statement inside browser resize event handler?

```
window.addEventListener("resize", handleBrowserResize);

function handleBrowserResize() {
  // your rest of the code to handle browser resize (if any)
  if (isBreakPoint(885)) {
    $('.header__register-link').appendTo($('.header__bottom'))
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you! i saw something like this in other post here, but couldnt figured out where to put it! Thank you once again)